# Error in the sentence "unload" using Informix

Tags: database, windows, informix

I try to use this sentence "unload" in Informix but it doesn't work:

```
UNLOAD TO 'p7024cargaP.unl' select * from p7024carga;
```

> ```
> [Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
> A syntax error has occurred.
> Script line 1, statement line 1, column 1
> ```

So maybe it is because I am using this sentence in Aqua Data Studio.

I have a Windows system in my pc.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNLOAD is not a command understood by the server.  Some tools, notably DB-Access, recognize the syntax and use a more or less complex sequence of operations to declare a cursor for the SELECT statement and then open the cursor, fetch each row, and format the result, writing to the named file.

Your primary option is to use DB-Access to execute the statement.  That is certainly the simplest.